# Allow Calendar Event Title on OS X Mavericks to show multi-line

Tags: macos, calendar

Is there a way I can see 2, 3 or 4 lines of text for one event in my OS X calendar?

It is currently just one line. A long time ago it used to be convenient to see the complete text at once. All of the text was shown in several lines in one event. Sometimes it was one line if I had a short event, but would expand to multiple lines when I had a longer title.

I'm not sure what happened to this cool feature!

Right now I have to write 4 separate short event titles, just to see a quick overview for today and only because a long titles disappear after one line is reached to the end.

It is convenient to see all information in a longer text with perhaps even up to 4 lines, so that I can quickly and easily see what is going on. One line is almost never enough for me. In fact, I see only the first 2 or 3 words if I am lucky.

I also don't want to click on every event just to see the last part of the 4 line text.

Is there a way to get it back to normal (or the way it used to be)?